# Pattern matching on one field of collection

Tags: c#, collections, properties, pattern-matching, field

Let's say that I have a class called car like this:

```
        public class Car
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public State State { get; set; }
        }

        public abstract record State(DateTime UpdatedAt)
        {
            protected State() : this(DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
            }
        }

        public record New : State;

        public record Damaged(int DamagedParts, string Description) : State;
```

and I fetched a list of cars with state damaged from database. It is a IReadOnlyCollection. How can I easily get properties of DamagedState (damaged parts and description) without iterating through the list? Can I use pattern matching for this?

Amount of fetched Cars can be up to 50k.

Comment: What is your db datamodel for `Car`?

Comment: I am using mongo DB so it is saved as is:
{
    "_id" : "74"
 "State" : {
 "_t" : "DamagedState"
 "DamagedParts" : 3
 "Description" : "Something wrong"
 "UpdatedAt" : ISODate("2022-08-25T12:03:22.673Z"),
 }
}

Comment: Do you need to distinctly index the unique damagedstates or do you want to see the damagedstates per car?

Comment: damagedStates per Car

Comment: Then you will probably have to iterate over the list. If performance is an issue, you can split the list into several subsets and iterate parallel over them and combine the results when finished.

As for a solution. Try `var result = cars.Where(c => c.State is Damaged);`
Let me know if it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this without iterating through the list. You will not have to iterate explicitly by using LINQ, but LINQ does iterate internally.

Since you cars list contains only cars with state `Damaged`, we don't need a `Where` clause:

```cs
List<(int CarId, int DamagedParts, string Description)> damaged = cars
    .Select(c => 
      (CarId: c.Id, ((Damaged)c.State).DamagedParts, ((Damaged)c.State).Description))
    .ToList();
```

This returns a list of tuples with the required info.

Or, easier:

```
List<(int CarId, Damaged Damage)> damaged = cars
    .Select(c => (CarId: c.Id, Damage: (Damaged)c.State))
    .ToList();
```

You can also defer execution and not call `.ToList()`. This will return an `IEnumerable<T>` that will iterate the original cars list without storing it in a new collection.

I do not see how pattern matching can help in this case.

If you want to be able to quickly select the damage by car Id:

```
Dictionary<int, Damaged> damageDict = cars
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c => (Damaged)c.State);

if (damageDict.TryGetValue(5, out var damage)) {

}
```

Comment: This solves my problem, will do it like this and check the performance

Comment: What you say in case of performance about this solution? 

var statesDictionary = cars.ToDictionary(car => car.Id, car.State as DamagedState);

and then get the states by searching it in dictionary by car id?

Comment: If you must select cars by id, a dictionary is in fact very efficient.